# An example of no linear map from a vector space to itself that satisfy $T(v+w)=T(v)+T(w)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

What is an example of a map $T$ from a complex vector space $C$ to itself such that $T(v+w)=T(v)+T(w)$. but $T$ is not linear.

Comment: Complex conjugation.

Comment: Complex conjugation?  You'd have $\overline{v+w}=\overline{v}+\overline{w}$ but $\overline{iv}\neq i\overline{v}$

Comment: What about $T(x+yi)=x, $ for $x,y\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: What if the vector space is $C^n$ instead?

Comment: @user42493 then take map which is additive on each coordinate,